# Determine build tools version from APK file

Tags: android, reverse-engineering, android-sdk-tools, apktool

Is it possible given a released APK file to know the Android build tools version used, especially with utilities like `zipalign` and `apksigner` that has been applied to the APK file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should run different commands to get some information:

1: `<sdk_path>\build-tools\version\aapt dump badging your_app.apk`

this command gives you some information about **sdkVersion**, **versionCode** **compileSdkVersion** and etc.

2: `<sdk_path>\build-tools\version\zipalign -c -v 4 your_app.apk`

this command at the end of outputs verifies that your_app is zipaligned or not.

3: `<jdk_path>\bin\jarsinger -verify -verbose -certs your_app.apk`

In the output of this command you'll find **CN** tag. It shows that your apk is signed with your keysign or it is debug version.

Comment: Ok. But can we determine the build tools version used to build the apk file. For example 29.0.2?

Comment: @Nederealm yes, the first command will show you which build tools were used. You could also decompile the APK using apktool and look at the AndroidManifest.xml yourself.